# dplyr group_by and cummean functions

Tags: r, dplyr

I expected the code below to output a data frame with three rows, each row representing the cumulative mean value of mpg after calculating the mean for each group of `cyl`:

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
arrange(cyl) %>%
group_by(cyl) %>%
summarise(running.mean.mpg = cummean(mpg))
```

This is what I expected to happen:

```
mean_cyl_4 <- mtcars %>% 
filter(cyl == 4) %>%
summarise(mean(mpg))

mean_cyl_4_6 <- mtcars %>% 
filter(cyl == 4 | cyl == 6) %>%
summarise(mean(mpg))

mean_cyl_4_6_8 <- mtcars %>% 
filter(cyl == 4 | cyl == 6 | cyl == 8) %>%
summarise(mean(mpg))

data.frame(cyl = c(4,6,8), running.mean.mpg = c(mean_cyl_4[1,1], mean_cyl_4_6[1,1], mean_cyl_4_6_8[1,1]))

  cyl running.mean.mpg
1   4     26.66364
2   6     23.97222
3   8     20.09062
```

How come `dplyr` seems to ignore `group_by(cyl)`?

Answer (score 5):

```
require("dplyr")

mtcars %>%
  arrange(cyl) %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  mutate(running.mean.mpg = cummean(mpg)) %>%
  select(cyl, running.mean.mpg)

# Source: local data frame [32 x 2]
# Groups: cyl
# 
# # cyl running.mean.mpg
# # 1    4         22.80000
# # 2    4         23.60000
# # 3    4         23.33333
# # 4    4         25.60000
# # 5    4         26.56000
# # 6    4         27.78333
# # 7    4         26.88571
# # 8    4         26.93750
```

For the sake of experimentation, this would also work with `data.table`. 
I mean, you have to load dplyr also to have `cummean()` available.

```
require("data.table")
DT <- as.data.table(mtcars)
DT[,j=list(
  running.mean.mpg = cummean(mpg)
  ), by="cyl"]
```

Comment: Martin that still isn't what I expected. See my edit which shows the data.frame I expected to be outputted

Comment: Well, it seems you are confusing what `group_by` should be doing. It groups based on a variable. What you are requesting now is a result (the mean) based on different filter conditions. Thats why `cummean` and `group_by` aren't working, they are ment for something else.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mutate` rather than `summarise`.

Answer (score 0):

This works as you want.

```
mtcars %>%
arrange(cyl) %>%
mutate(running.mean.mpg = cummean(mpg)) %>%
select(cyl, running.mean.mpg)%>%
group_by(cyl)%>%
summarize(target=last(running.mean.mpg))
```