# Calculation of consecutive means and percentiles

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the dataset,

```
zz <- data.frame(IP=c(2.0,1.8,2.8,3.1,5.3), 
                 A=c(18,14,16,20,21), 
                 B=c(27,20,26,31,29))
```

and I want to sort the dataframe based on IP and calculate the means of A and median of B from each row onwards.
The result should be

```
mean_A=c(17.8,18.8,19.0,20.5,21.0), 
medians_B=c(27,28,29,30,29))
```

Ideally, I would also like to be able to select afterwards the dataframe based in the mean. For example, select the items for which the mean of A is at least 19, which would be the last three rows.
I tried the code

```
zz %>%
  arrange(IP) %>%
  mutate(mean.A = cummean(A)) %>%
  select(IP, mean.A>=19)
```

but the cummean does not exactly does what I wished, and the select does not find the mean.A.

I explored the questions [dplyr group_by and cummean functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23174034/dplyr-group-by-and-cummean-functions), [How to find the means of consecutive numbers in a column given consecutive string of another column in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36090398/how-to-find-the-means-of-consecutive-numbers-in-a-column-given-consecutive-strin) and others with no success.
Is this doable? Is it the right approach?

Comment: Can you explain the calculation of `mean_A` and `medians_B` ? How do you get those numbers ?

Comment: your question is incomplete. Where do you get 17.8 from? what about 18.8? etc for the means? Can you also explain how you came up with the medians

Comment: For clarification on the calculation of the means and medians. After sorting based on IP you get `zz <- data.frame(IP=c(1.8,2.0,2.8,3.1,5.3), A=c(14,18,16,20,21), 
  B=c(20,27,26,31,29))`. The mean of A for the five values is 17.8, removing the 1st row (witht the smallest IP) is 18.75; removing the two smallest IP rows you get 19 (16+20+21/3) and so on. Same approach for calculation of medians.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
zz%>%
    mutate(meanA = rev(cummean(rev(A))),
            MedianB = rev(map_dbl(n():1,~median(B[.x:n()]))))
   IP  A  B meanA MedianB
1 2.0 18 27 17.80    27.0
2 1.8 14 20 17.75    27.5
3 2.8 16 26 19.00    29.0
4 3.1 20 31 20.50    30.0
5 5.3 21 29 21.00    29.0
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is particularly useful for the Median calculations.  I also tried to subset the dataframe afterwards for which the mean A is for example at least 19 using 
%>%filter(zz,meanA>19), 
but I get Error: Result must have length 5, not 15.   The aimed result would be something like zz <- data.frame(IP=c(2.8,3.1,5.3), A=c(16,20,21), B=c(26,31,29)). Any other idea? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
zz %>%
arrange(IP) %>%
mutate(mean.A = sapply(A, function(x)mean(ifelse(zz$A >= x, zz$A, NA), na.rm = T)))
```

There's probably a fully piped solution which doesn't require interaction with the parent data frame but I'm not clever enough to work it out.